# Formatting 0 (zero) in labels as 000 (i.e. 3 digits) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, format

Is there a possibility in QGIS to format 0 (zero) as 000 (3 digits)? I.e. can I define the minimum number of digits a number should be represented by?

Answer (score 3):

As this is for labelling, you can write a simple expression to handle it:

`if(length("FIELD")<3, lpad("FIELD",3,'0'), "FIELD")`

Basically, if the field is less than 3 characters, it will be left-padded with 0s.

Comment: @ Tom Brennan: Thanks. 
Your suggestion does, what I hoped it would, adding the zeroes in front of the number.
A length of 1.046m (1,046m), which in my case in the stationing format (0+000 for 0.000, or 1,000) would have turned out as "1+46", is now displayed correctly as "1+046".

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do it with standard QGIS expressions, so I write a python function to do it that can then be used in QGIS expressions.

In the Expression Dialog (eg when setting labels for points) go to the Function Editor and make a new file by hitting the green + sign (lower left). Name it something like "formatter" and use the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def pyformat(value1, value2):
    """
return value1 formatted by value2
    """
    return value2.format(value1)
```

Then in the expression editor you can format values using any python format string, for example `{:03}` formats the value with 3 characters including leading zeroes. Do this with a label expression of `pyformat("score", '{:03}')` which will turn `1` into `001`, `0` into `000`, `123` into `123`, and `9999` into `9999`.

Read up on python formatting for more - you can control numbers of decimal points, leading +/- signs etc. I'm surprised I couldn't find a QGIS expression that could do this, maybe I missed it. Possibly it can be done with `format_number` and some padding with zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for labelling purposes, why not to use the following formula on the Expression Dialog for labels?

```
"LABEL" || '00'
```

[image]
In this way, you will simply append two zeroes to the label that already contains one zero.

Comment: It's worthwhile adding the formula into the body of the answer, and not just as a screenshot